# Windows Server 2008 Domain Controller Not Allowing Local Logins

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

I have a Windows Server 2008 Domain Controller which has recently decided to refuse logins to the server, and has dropped off the domain.  I can still access the C$ share, but all attempts to login either locally or remotely via Remote Desktop results in an 'incorrect username or password'.

The AD service on the server is also unavailable to other systems in the domain.

Can anyone suggest a way to recover this server to the point where I can log into it again?  This is my last resort before reverting to a backup or reinstall.

Regards

Moo

Answer (score 4):

I would reinstall.  You might be able to get it working again, but *can you trust it in the future*?  DCs aren't things you go idly hacking at, they're the most important servers on your network so you need to be certain they're rock solid.

The restore option is one I would discard, as you run the risk of also restoring whatever made it go screwy in the first place.